# Views returned based on variable and existence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) website I am working on. The site is meant to as a basis for multiple clients all with their own unique business requirements. For any given controller method, I may or may not have a customized view for the client based on their `ClientId`.

Right now how I am handling this is through a `ResourceSelectorObject` like so:

```
public class ClientResourceSelector
{
    public ClientResourceSelector(int clientId)
    {
        this.ClientId = clientId;
    }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public readonly List<ViewProfile> ViewProfiles = new List<ViewProfile>()
    {
        new ViewProfile { ClientId = 8, Controller = "Contact", Action = "NewContact", View = "C008/NewContact" }
    };

    public string ViewName(string controller, string action)
    {
        var Profile = ViewProfiles.FirstOrDefault(X => X.Controller.Equals(controller) && X.Action.Equals(action) && X.ClientId == ClientId);
        if (Profile == null) return string.Empty;
        return Profile.View;
    }
}
```

Then in the code, I use that object in this manner:

```
// GET: Contact/NewContact
public ActionResult NewContact()
{
     var selector = new ClientResourceSelector(ClientId);
     string alternate_view = selector.ViewName("Contact", "NewContact");
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(alternate_view))
         return View(NewContactViewModel.Instance(ClientId));
     else
         return View(alternate_view, NewContactViewModel.Instance(ClientId));
}
```

The problem, and this is definitely the programming equivalent of "First World Problems," but I would like to still be able to just call `View(viewModel)` and have it select the appropriate view to display programmatically without my having to remember to  register each view in the selector.

Obviously, I would then want to override the `View()` method in the abstract controller that all of my controllers are inheriting from. But I am unsure of how that code would look. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I would highly recommend overriding the ViewEngine and creating a MultiTentant ViewEngine. [This article might help](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/advanced-uses-razor-views-asp-net-mvc/).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the ViewEngine -- though I kind of suspected its existence. I will Google it and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I've created ones in the past.  Most of the Tenant systems I've built use some type of route/request parameter (could easily be updated to use DNS or wahtever, you have a lot of options) to determine the specific Tenant.  I use an action filter that executes before any controller (or routing) to populate the route data (useful for Tenant specific routes as well).

```
public class TenantActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    internal const string _Tenant = "tenant";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do this how ever you want, right now I'm using querystring
        // Could be changed to use DNS name or whatever
        var tenant = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[_Tenant] as string;

        if (tenant != null)
        {
            filterContext.RouteData.Values[Tenant] = tenant;
        }
    }
}
```

Either globally register the action filter:

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

(Or using a Dependency Injection Framework)

Then a custom ViewEngine:

```
public class TenantViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{

    private string GetPrefix(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        var tenant = controllerContext.RouteData.Values[TenantActionFilterAttribute.Tenant] as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenant))
        {
            result = "Tenants/" + tenant + "/";
        }

        return result;
    }
    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        var prefix = GetPrefix(controllerContext);

        if (partialPath.StartsWith("~/"))
        {
            partialPath = partialPath.Insert(2, prefix);
        }
        else if (partialPath.StartsWith("~") || partialPath.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            partialPath = partialPath.Insert(1, prefix);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialPath))
        {
            partialPath = prefix + partialPath;
        }

        return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath);
    }
    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var prefix = GetPrefix(controllerContext);

        if (viewPath.StartsWith("~/"))
        {
            viewPath = viewPath.Insert(2, prefix);
        }
        else if (viewPath.StartsWith("~") || viewPath.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            viewPath = viewPath.Insert(1, prefix);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewPath))
        {
            viewPath = prefix + viewPath;
        }

        if (masterPath.StartsWith("~/"))
        {
            masterPath = masterPath.Insert(2, prefix);
        }
        else if (masterPath.StartsWith("~") || masterPath.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            masterPath = masterPath.Insert(1, prefix);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPath))
        {
            masterPath = prefix + masterPath;
        }

        return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
    }
}
```

I can't exactly remember how this works, but the search paths change from the default to something very close to:

```
"~/Tenants/<TenantName>/Areas/{3}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",  
"~/Areas/{3}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",  
"~/Tenants/<TenantName>//Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",  
"~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",  
"~/Tenants/<TenantName>//Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",  
"~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
```

Where 1:Controller, 2:View/Action, 3:AreaName