# How to handle different category of logged in user in asp.met mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am in learning phase of ASP.Net MVC 5 web development and I am stuck at one place. So, I have a website which will have three flow.

1. Non loggedin user
2. Authenticated user (Tenants)
3. Authenticated user (Owner)

Now during registration I have simply added a checkbox to capture if user is going to be a tenant or owner. **Now the view file for all three (non loggedin, owner and tenant) needs to be different.**

As of now I know how to handle `two type of user (non-logged in and (tenant)logged in)`. In my `_ViewStart.cshtml` file I did something like below

```
@{   
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInLayout.cshtml";
    }
else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    } 
}
```

So far so good. But you can clearly see there is no identificaiton of "Tenant and Owner User". Given the fact that I will have a property during registration which will be true or false for tenant and owner.

I want to do something like below

```
@{   
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
     if(User.IsTenant)
     {Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoggedTenantLayout.cshtml";
     }
     else{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInOwnerlayout.cshtml";
     }      
    }
else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    } 
}
```

But I read something about **Areas, and then Route**. So, I am confused, if you all have three type of user Flow, what method you would have followed. I mean do I need to do some **route manipulation** or something. Can someone please guide me here. I know there is something called **Roles** too. But I think that is for adding extra privilege in a page by adding may be some edit button or something. As I am beginner, can some one tell me how can I have tenant,owner and non logged in user flow separated out.

> Owner needs to see a totally different view file and options and same
>   goes with tenant. I know this question is kind of broad but if someone can give me a basic small code snippet on how to separate out the flow, I can take it forward from there.

Comment: I assume you are using ASP.NET Identity for the user authentication?

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner. so, I do not have any fancy authentication in place. I am just learning. Kindly guide me,

Comment: @Juan: If you can kindly guide me or if you can tell me about any link, from where I can understand/study these stuffs then that will also suffice. Thanks

Comment: @Juan: requirement is that tenant views will have different menu options altogether than that of owner

Comment: If you're going to build a real tenant system, take a look at my [code to return views based on tenants via a custom ViewEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446944/views-returned-based-on-variable-and-existence/44448490#44448490)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I someday plan to make the website  "Actually Live". I will definitely look into your link and will ask futher doubts accordingly. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @Unbreakable if you have any questions about that code, please ask in the comments of that question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Got it. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path forward depends on the answer to this question: are tenants and owners distinct user types or simply permission sets? People often conflate these two. As it stands, it looks as if you're just looking to treat "tenants" one way and "owners" another, which can be easily solved via roles. Essentially, a tenant gets assigned a role like "Tenant" and an owner gets assigned a role like "Owner". Then, you can protect certain controllers/actions for one role or the other via:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
```

Which would then only allow owners to access that. For something like including a different layout. You can branch on `User.IsInRole`:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Tenant"))
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoggedTenantLayout.cshtml";
}
else if (User.IsInRole("Owner"))
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInOwnerlayout.cshtml";
}
else
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If, however, these are distinct user types, where you need to collect and persist entirely different types of information, then you should handle it via type inheritance. For example, a tenant might have like `MonthlyPayment`, whereas that type of information makes no sense for a an owner. In that scenario, you'd do:

```
public class Tenant : ApplicationUser
{
    // Tenant-specific properties
}

public class Owner : ApplicationUser
{
    // Owner-specific properties
}

public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    // Shared properties
}
```

By default, Entity Framework will handle this type of inheritance by creating a single database table with columns for all the user types, along with a `Discriminator` column. The `Discriminator` column will hold the class name that was saved, i.e. one of "Tenant", "Owner", or "ApplicationUser", which Entity Framework will then use to instantiate the right type when you query out users.

For the most part, this works just fine, but you must be aware that you cannot have non-nullable columns on any derived types. This is due to the fact that other derived types or the base type won't be able to fill this column, because they won't have that property. You can still enforce that a particular property is required for the purposes of something like a form collecting user input, via a view model, though; it just can't be enforced at the database level.

If that's a deal-breaker or you just don't like having everything in a single table, you can choose to use a table-per-type inheritance strategy. With that, you'd have a table for each type, `ApplicationUser`, `Tenant`, and `Owner`. However, the table for `ApplicationUser` would hold all the base columns and everything shared between all user types, while the derived-type tables will only hold columns specific to their unique properties. To use this type of inheritance strategy, simply add the `Table` attribute to your derived types:

```
[Table("Tenants")]
public class Tenant : ApplicationUser
```

Comment: Okey. I am little confused now. Basically, if during registration I mark **User A as tenant** and **User B as Owner**. And suppose I follow the `Role` solution that you have shown me. What if in future User A (tenant) also wants to act as owner and wants to see the options that owner can see. How can I handle it. Since his role is assigned as Tenant. Do, I need to tell him to go to register page again and then register as a owner too, but that's a big hassle right? Am I misising something here. I don't think registering same person again would be the ideal way? Can you kindly guide me a little

Comment: How to handle a sitaution where same person can act as owner and tenant too. Do I need to make him register twice? If the ideal way to make them register again. then do let me know.

Comment: No. In case of roles, you can assign multiple, so that's not an issue. You would need to figure out what happens with things like your layout if a user is in multiple roles, but that's just business logic. You might consider, for example developing separate portals for tenants and owners, limited to that particular role. A user with both could then log in to either one.

Comment: So, when some one logs in I want to redirect to their own controller accordingly. So I can do something like below in the HOMECONTROLLER  right? `public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("Tenant"))
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tenant");
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Owner");
            }
            return View();
        }`

Comment: Kindly note that I will put all the "role level safeguards" at controller level in both "tenant" and "owner" later. But initial redirection I can do like above right?

Comment: Also, note that I have added the initial layout partial view with conditional statement in the shared folder the way you explained me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two concepts at play here:

- Authentication (logged in or not)
- Authorization (Tenant, Owner)

You have already figured out the Authentication piece.

For the Authorization, you can use Roles. The general idea is that you are going to assign your users a role when they sign up (based on your checkbox). From there on, you can check to see which role the user belongs to and route them appropriately.

There are many ways for you to handle how you serve the content. One of them is `Areas`. You could in theory create an area for Tenants and an area for Owners, although this may prove overkill for your learning purposes.

Check out the following tutorial for implementation details:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into it now and will upvote/accept/comment 
 on your answer in a bit accordingly. Can you kindly tell me one thing, so, in my case I do not need to touch the route file right? I mean I can handle everything via roles. No need to play with routes right?

Comment: It really depends on how you end up implementing things. One way of implementing the views the user gets could be Routing but I don't think you need to do that. Selectively displaying navigation based on roles and properly securing your controllers with Authorization attributes should be enough.

Comment: One more thing. As the name implies, "Routing" is about taking a request and forwarding it appropriately based on some logic. There are a number of reasons why one would want to route the requests. Your case could be one of them, if you choose to implement it that way. I personally follow the KISS principle. Simple is better.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to follow the `Roles` approach first. And I will see how it turns out to be. If I get doubts or anything I will comment here. Currently, I am in office, once I go home I will try your answer and other valuable inputs that you have provided. :)

Comment: What if a situation comes where, same person who registered as tenant wants to now work as owner too. So in that case do i need to tell him to register again as Owner and then add another role for that user again separately. Just curious

Comment: No need. You would just have to add that user to the role "Owner".

Comment: With your and Chris's answer, I added the role. And now I want to have seperate controller for tenant and owner, So, when some one logs in I want to redirect to their own controller accordingly. So I can do something like below in the HOMECONTROLLER right? `public ActionResult Index() { if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { if (User.IsInRole("Tenant")) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tenant"); else return RedirectToAction("Index", "Owner"); } return View(); }`

Comment: Kindly note that I will put all the "role level safeguards" at controller level in both "tenant" and "owner" later. But initial redirection I can do like above right?

Comment: I mean after loggin in obviously I want them to get redirected to their own page. Am I doing things correctly. Please guide me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151999/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-juan).